# scheme format function missing from gambit

Tags: scheme, guile, gambit

I attempted to run a gambit scheme script that was previously run with guile. I noticed that gambit fails because it is missing the "format" function.

Is format not part of scheme?

```
(format #t "example(~a)=<~a>\n" i (example i))
```

Instead I modified my gambit script to the following.

```
(display (string-append "example(" (number->string i) ")=<" (number->string (example i)) ">\n"))
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: It's not part of any Scheme standard. There's a similar facility in SRFI 28.

Answer (score 4):

In Gambit you can use standard R7RS libraries and you need to import SRFI-28 that contain format function.

```lisp
(import (srfi 28))
```

But Scheme format function as defined by SRFI-28 don't have `#t` argument that print to stdout like Common Lips have. First argument is always output string pattern:

```lisp
(display (format "example(~a)=<~a>\n" i (example i)))
(newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

SRFI 28 is quite limited.

You can write yourself a macro, which provides a similar functionality:

```lisp
(define-syntax printf
  (syntax-rules (~s ~a ~%)
    ((_ ~s arg . rest) (begin (write   arg) (printf . rest)))
    ((_ ~a arg . rest) (begin (display arg) (printf . rest)))
    ((_ ~%     . rest) (begin (newline)     (printf . rest)))
    ((_ arg    . rest) (printf ~a arg . rest))
    ((_) (void))))
```

This gives you a `printf` which understands `~a`, `~s` and `~%`:

```lisp
(let ((i 42) (example sqrt))
  (printf "example(" ~a i ")=<" ~a (example i) ">\n"))
```

Or even shorter:

```lisp
(let ((i 42) (example sqrt))
  (printf "example(" i ")=<" (example i) ">\n"))
```

`~~` is not necessary, because the format directives are stand-alone symbols instead of embedded strings. SRFI 28 gives you nothing more.